# Deleting password from mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to delete the password from the password field in the members table in the mysql.

I have these codes which will work if if I change the $password and password to $id and id but then it will remove the entire user account. I just need to remove/delete the users password.

delete.php

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username=""; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name=""; // Database name
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// get value of id that sent from address bar
$id=$_GET['id'];

// Delete data in mysql from row that has this id
$sql="DELETE FROM $tbl_name WHERE password='$password'"; <<<< if i change this to id=$id the script will work but it will remove the entire account!! 
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully deleted
if($result){
echo "Deleted Successfully";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='suspend.php'>Back to main page</a>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?>

<?php
// close connection
mysql_close();
?>
```

and this is my List.php

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username=""; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name=""; // Database name
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// select record from mysql
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
?>

<table width="400" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<td colspan="5" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Delete data in mysql</strong> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Id</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Username</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Email</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Pass</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<tr>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['username']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['email']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['password']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><a href="delete_ac.php?id=<? echo $rows['id']; ?>">Ban and Remove</a></td>
</tr>

<?php
// close while loop
}
?>

</table>

<?php
// close connection;
mysql_close();
?>
```

How can i just delete/remove the password field in the members table ?

Comment: You'll need to do an `UPDATE` instead of `DELETE` in that case. `UPDATE $tbl_name SET password="" WHERE userid="x"`

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 3):

RDBMS' don't work on columns, they work on rows. INSERT, SELECT, DELETE and UPDATE are all intended to work in the context of a *row*, not of a *column*.

What this means is that, if you want to "remove" a password from a user, what you really want to do is `UPDATE` the password to be `NULL` for that user (`WHERE user_id = 12345`).

If you issue a `DELETE`, regardless of your `WHERE` criteria, you are telling the database to remove the row entirely. This means that the database will no longer contain that user at all.

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes, but given that the OP us still using `mysql_*` functions and is vulnerable to SQL injection...

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is `UPDATE` the record, not `DELETE` it,

```
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET password = '' WHERE id='$id'";
```

Comment: No, i need to empty the password field. which means i need to delete it.

Comment: No, UPDATE to '' will empty the field. Or set it to NULL

Comment: @roozfar You can't delete an entire column from just one row.

Answer (score 0):

You don t remove a field. You simply update it to NULL or empty:

```
$sql="UPDATE $table_name SET password='' where id=$id"; <<<< if i change this to id=$id the script will work but it will remove the entire account!! 
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

OR

```
$sql="UPDATE $table_name SET password=NULL where id=$id"; <<<< if i change this to id=$id the script will work but it will remove the entire account!! 
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: I dont want to remove the field. I need to empty the field for that specif user.

Comment: Well, my answer empty s the field

Comment: I used your code and the above codes but it doesn't work and I get "ERROR" message showing!!! any suggestions ?